# Constraint propagation with modulo

Tags: z3, z3py

Say I have two variables a and b. I would like to define the following relation/constraint between them:

- a = 1, b % 12 = 1 or b % 12 = 0
- a = 2, b % 12 = 0

Some solutions are

- a = 1, b = 1
- a = 1, b = 12
- a = 2, b = 12

I'm currently modelling this in a straightforward way (and adding an extra condition on top):

```py
rhs = Or(
  And(a == 1, Or(b % 12 == 1, b % 12 == 0)),
  And(a == 2, Or(b % 12 == 0))
)
lhs = And(b > 10)
solver.add(Implies(lhs, rhs))
```

However, this becomes very slow as I increase the number of variables and constraints.

Is there a better way to model this? Maybe a function? But I would like to allow search to run "in both directions", i.e. given a value of b, we should be able to identify a value of a, and vice versa.

Comment: Division and modulus is always difficult for SMT solvers. There probably is a better encoding, but it's hard to say without seeing some more details. Stack-overflow works the best if you're clear on what problem you're exactly trying to solve at the high-level, so more details are needed here for a better answer. Also, be aware of the XY problem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'm essentially trying to use Z3 as a constraint solver. This particular problem is a musical CSP, so a is a chord and b is a note, and they constrain each other. The modulo normalises away octaves, e.g. for some chord, we can have note i or i+12 (an octave up) or i+24, etc. I also tried replacing the modulo with the disjunction of all possible notes, but that wasn't any faster.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your comment, it looks like the use of integers is unnecessarily complicating your constraints.

If you need to stick to "numbers" for some other reason, then I'd recommend asserting `0 <= b` and `b < 12` globally (to represent all 12 notes), which can help the solver reduce the search space. However, division/modulus are always hard for SMT solvers, but perhaps you do not need them at all: In fact, I'd recommend not using numbers to represent notes in the first place. Instead use an enumeration:

```py
Note, (A, B, C) = EnumSort('Note', ('A', 'B', 'C'))
```

(I've only written the first three above; you can add the remaining 9.)

This very clearly communicates to the solver that you're dealing with a finite collection of distinct items. You should also consider representing octave as some enum-type, or at least restrict it to be in some small range that covers the first 6-7 octaves which I assume you're interested in.

You can read more about enums in z3 here: https://ericpony.github.io/z3py-tutorial/advanced-examples.htm (Scroll down to the part that talks about "enumerations.")

You haven't told us how octaves/notes constrain each other in your system; but it should be easy to capture them using regular functions that take octaves and return possible notes. You should post actual code that people can run so they can see what the bottle-necks can be.

Comment: op is a no-show, but wanted to say this is helpful for someone new to z3 to see how to frame a problem